# Is this patent enforceable?

Tags: patent-lifetime, lapsed-patent

In reference to the patent: [US6667877](https://www.google.com/patents/US6667877)

Google says the fees are lapsed on this patent. IS this still enforceable?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair), this patent's status is "Patent Expired Due to NonPayment of Maintenance Fees Under 37 CFR 1.362" as of 01-21-2008. While there might theoretically be a way to pay those fees and reinstate the patent, considering its been almost 10 years, I kind of doubt they will do so. According to the [USPTO](https://www.uspto.gov/patents-maintaining-patent/maintain-your-patent), here are the rules for trying to reinstate an expired patent due to nonpayment of fees.

> **Reinstate an expired patent**
>
> If a maintenance fee has not been paid in a timely manner and the owner of the patent wants to get the patent rights reinstated, a petition and proper fees are required.
>
> What are the petition requirements?
>
> Any petition to accept an
> unintentionally delayed payment of a maintenance fee must include:
>
> 1. the required maintenance fee set forth in § 1.20(e) through (g)
> 2. the petition fee as set forth in § 1.17(m)
> 3. a statement that the delay in payment of the maintenance fee was unintentional
> 4. be signed in compliance with § 1.33(b).

I think it may be hard to justify over nine years of nonpayment as unintentional although I suppose they could try. I am not a lawyer so there may be more to this and I hope one of the patent attorneys that contribute will provide more information.